# looking for element always returns false in Watir-Classic

Tags: html, ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

```
<div class="wizardPanel box cf" id="wizardPanel">
    <p class="validation-msg error visually-hidden" id="error0"><span data-icon="warn"></span>Your departure and arrival cites must be different. Please correct the highlighted fields below.</p>
    <p class="validation-msg error visually-hidden" id="error1"><span data-icon="warn"></span>The return date must be later than the departure date. Please select a different date.</p>
    <p class="validation-msg error visually-hidden" id="error2"><span data-icon="warn"></span>Sorry, we're able to book only 1 to 6 passengers total per itinerary.</p>
    <p class="validation-msg error visually-hidden" id="error3"><span data-icon="warn"></span>Please select the ages of the children traveling.</p>
    <p class="validation-msg error visually-hidden" id="error4"><span data-icon="warn"></span>We are only able to book one infant in lap per traveler aged 12+.</p>
    <p class="validation-msg error visually-hidden" id="error5"><span data-icon="warn"></span>Children must not be allowed to travel without either a Senior or Adult.</p>
    <p class="validation-msg error visually-hidden" id="error6"><span data-icon="warn"></span>Please check the date highlighted below. Date format should be mm/dd/yy.</p>
    <p class="validation-msg error visually-hidden" id="error7"><span data-icon="warn"></span>Departure airport field is empty. Please enter correct airport name.</p>
    <p class="validation-msg error visually-hidden" id="error8"><span data-icon="warn"></span>Arrival airport field is empty. Please enter correct airport name.</p>
</div>
```

In the above HTML markup, I am trying to find whether the text is visible to the user or not. 
For that I am using the following code which works well with Watir-webDriver, but not in Watir-Classic(always returns `false`):

```
@browser.div(:id => 'wizardPanel').p(:id => 'error2')..present?
```

Can someone help me to make it work across the FireFox, IE, Chrome browsers?

Comment: Based on the class, 'visually-hidden', of the paragraph elements, I would think that the element is not visible. Therefore, `false` would be expected. Can you share the styles for the elements?

Comment: <div class="wizardPanel box cf" id="wizardPanel">
        <p class="validation-msg error visually-hidden" id="error1" style="display: none; "><span data-icon="warn"></span>The return date must be later than the departure date. Please select a different date.</p>
        <p class="validation-msg error visually-hidden" id="error2" style="display: block; "><span data-icon="warn"></span>Sorry, we're able to book only 1 to 6 passengers total per itinerary.</p>
    </div>

Comment: I still cannot reproduce your problem using watir-classic. Any chance it is a public page you are testing? Are you performing an action that causes the message to go from hidden to visible? It could be a timing issue.

Comment: Is that a typo with 2 .. Before present?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
@browser.div(:id => 'wizardPanel').p(:id => 'error2').visible?
```